# Replacing XML tags values to Null/No value using Stax and writing to another XML file

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am having hard time to replace Persons.xml tag values to NULL using stax and then send all outputs to another fakePersons.xml file using XMLEventWriter. However, When I am trying to run below code, it is only changing address tag  . I need same behaviour for all 4 tags.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Persons.xml**

```html
<ADocument>
    <Stuff>
        <StuffA></StuffA>
    </Stuff>
    <OtherStuff>
        <OtherStuff>
            <ABC>YOU KAY</ABC>
        </OtherStuff>
    </OtherStuff>

    <Person>
        <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
        <firstName>Some </firstName>
        <lastName>Person </lastName>
        <personID id ="3" name="PID">111111111111</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
        <firstName id ="1" name="ID">Another Person</firstName>
        <address>Main St. 2</address>
        <personID>222222222222</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
        <firstName>Some</firstName>
        <lastName>Person</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>

    <MoreStuff>
        <foo></foo>
        <foo>fooo</foo>
        <foo><bar></bar></foo>
        <foo>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar/>
            <bar>bb</bar>
        </foo>
        <bar/>
    </MoreStuff>

</ADocument>
```

```js
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;


public class ReplaceXmlWithFakeUser
{
 private static final String PERSON="Person";
 private static final String PERSON_ID="personID";
    private static final String PERSON_FIRST_NAME="firstName";
 private static final String PERSON_LAST_NAME="lastName";
 private static final String PERSON_ADDRESS="address";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException
  {
    XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = inFactory.createXMLEventReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\naeem_xml\\persons.xml")));
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventWriter writer = factory.createXMLEventWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\naeem_xml\\fakePersons.xml")));
    XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
 int person_rec_no =0;
 XMLEvent event = null;
    while (eventReader.hasNext())
    {
       event = eventReader.nextEvent();
      if (event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&  event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON))
      {
        writer.add(event);
        Person fakePerson=getFakePerson();;
        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
   
        while(!(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT && event.asEndElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON)))
        {
          if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT &&  event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON_ID))
          {
    writer.add(event);
    writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.personId));
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
          }
    
          if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON_FIRST_NAME))
          {
    writer.add(event);
    writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.firstName));
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
          }
          if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON_LAST_NAME))
          {
        writer.add(event);
               writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.lastName));
      event = eventReader.nextEvent();
          }
          if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT && event.asStartElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON_ADDRESS))
          {
      writer.add(event);
                writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(fakePerson.address));
       event = eventReader.nextEvent();
          }
    else
          writer.add(event);
          event = eventReader.nextEvent();
  }
  if(event.getEventType() == XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT && event.asEndElement().getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(PERSON))
          {
    writer.add(event);
          }
   }
      else
      {
        writer.add(event);
      }
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  private static Person getFakePerson()
  {
  
    //create simple fake user...

    Person fakePerson = new Person();
    fakePerson.personId = null;
    fakePerson.firstName = null;
    fakePerson.lastName = null;
    fakePerson.address = null;
    return fakePerson;
  }

  static class Person
  {
    String personId;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String address;

  }
}
```

**fakePersons.xml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" ?><ADocument>
    <Stuff>
        <StuffA></StuffA>
    </Stuff>
    <OtherStuff>
        <OtherStuff>
            <ABC>yada yada</ABC>
        </OtherStuff>
    </OtherStuff>

    <Person>
        <uuid>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</uuid>
        <firstName>Some </firstName>
        <lastName>Person </lastName>
        <personID id="3" name="PID">111111111111</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</uuid>
        <firstName id="1" name="ID">Another Person</firstName>
        <address></address>
        <personID>222222222222</personID>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <uuid>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</uuid>
        <firstName>Some</firstName>
        <lastName>Person</lastName>
        <personID>111111111111</personID>
    </Person>

    <MoreStuff>
        <foo></foo>
        <foo>fooo</foo>
        <foo><bar></bar></foo>
        <foo>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar></bar>
            <bar>bb</bar>
        </foo>
        <bar></bar>
    </MoreStuff>

</ADocument>
```

Comment: Unless you're dealing with a lot of data, XSLT is a better tool for XML manipulation than StAX.

Comment: Thanks David.. I am new to java world and know nothing about XSLT implementation....There will be atleast 50 files and data will be at least 130 MB in each file but may go up, and all these files need to be manipulated parallely. so thought of using Stax..

Comment: Check out [STX](http://stx.sourceforge.net/) and [Joost](http://joost.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used them personally, though.